R package: dependency packages not loaded despite being in DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE
I am trying to create my own R package with has dependencies on other packages. Based on the many resources available, I have those dependencies listed in both the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files (via devtools and roxygenize, not manually):
In DESCRIPTION:
Imports:
    data.table,
    ggplot2

In NAMESPACE:
import(data.table)
import(ggplot2)

I then created my package via:
> library(devtools)
Loading required package: usethis
> devtools::install()

I close R and re-open it, and can directly load my package via:
library(mypackage)

No error messages but no Loading required package: comment either like above for library(devtools).
And sure enough, basic functions won't work because depenedent packages were not loaded:
> as.data.table(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
Error in as.data.table(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)) : 
  could not find function "as.data.table"

I feel I'm really close but still something missing.
[I read multiple online resources, most common error is having dependent packages in DESCRIPTION but not in NAMESPACE, but that is not my issue.
I expected the dependent packages to be loaded as part of the library(mypackage) command.]

If you want the package to load you need depends rather than imports.
